# Spring Data @OneToMany relationship with @JoinTable - How to fix foreign key constraint violation?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

How can I fix foreign key constraint violation when using Spring Data @OneToMany relationship with @JoinTable?

Models:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Email {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "email_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "email_seq", sequenceName = "email_seq")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "email_attachment",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EMAIL_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ATTACHMENT_ID")
    )
    private List<Attachment> attachments;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Attachment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "attachment_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "attachment_generator", sequenceName = "attachment_seq")
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

When I try to delete `Attachment` like this:

```
attachmentRepository.delete(id)
```

it throws following error:

> ERROR: update or delete on table "attachment" violates foreign key constraint "email_attachment_attachment_id_fkey" on table "email_attachment"
>     Details: Key (id)=(6) is still referenced from table "email_attachment".

Comment: You will also need to add cascadetype with @OneToMany annotation.

Comment: As @22kar said, have a look at the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#cascade()) for cascade types

Comment: Adding `OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)` doesn't help.

Comment: If deleting the "N" side of a 1-N unidir you first need to remove it from any relations that point to it ... i.e remove it from the Collection in `Email`

Comment: @BillyFrost that was my plan B. Isn't it possible to do it automagically?

Comment: If you are using hibernate 5.x, it will create its own foreign keys and associate it with entities. In that case, you will have to explicitly specify foreign key name on the JoinTable annotation using @ForeignKey. I recently came across this issue.

Comment: How can an `Attachment` know about what refers to it when you haven't made relations BIDIR? There is no "automagic".

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the relation in `Attachment` too with `@ManyToOne`.

**Attachment.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Attachment {
    // ...

    @ManyToOne(mappedBy = "attachments")
    private Email email;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do that as `Attachment` is also referenced by the second table the same as with email.

Comment: I think I prefer to keep this relation unidirectional.

Comment: In that case I think BillyFrost suggestion is the best.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `javax.persistence.CascadeType` in JPA that will remove the corresponding entries from the *parent table* like that

```
@Entity
class Employee {

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Address address;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Option is to first delete `email` before deleting `attachment` object.

Answer (score 0):

Another choice would be to manually remove the attachment from the email. This would also cause the row in the join table to be deleted.
If you combine this with `orphanRemoval=true`, the attachment will be deleted automatically.

Comment: Where should I put `orphanRemoval=true`?

Comment: orphanRemoval is a setting of @OneToMany (on Email.attachments).